# Racing MMO - 2D or 3D - Massively Multiplayer Online Racing Games

Tags: software-recommendation, games

I really like multiplayer racing games, like Need for Speed World or similar.

I wonder if there is any MMO racing game for Ubuntu (2D or 3D). Browser-based games are also accepted.

**Note:**

I tried this question in the Gaming Q&A of StackExchange (see link below), but one user said that my question was off-topic.

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16329/racing-mmo-for-linux-2d-or-3d-massively-multiplayer-online-racing-games

Comment: This particular genre has only one possible answer until now and, thus, this question is not too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only native MMO close to racing is [Darkwind: War on Wheels](http://www.dark-wind.com/).

> Darkwind: War on Wheels is an independently developed 3D turn based racing and vehicle combat massively multiplayer online game (MMOG) for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. It is inspired by the tabletop game Car Wars and the Mad Max movies, but set in its own original universe.

Also you can try other racing MMOGs in wine.  (p.s. nfs world doesn't work)

Comment: +1 Excellent answer! You've found the impossible!